# How to access device features from browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

My new project is mobile website, it will run in any mobile browser like for iOS, Blackberry, Windows, Android. In that my client want to get device features like photo library, camera and date picker for all types of devices using Phonegap, js file etc.

I just want to know is it possible using Phonegap. Also is mobile website can possible with responsive design and only showing data from the web service for all mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do those things with phonegap, but not as a mobile website. Phonegap is for creating apps using familiar web technologies like CSS and JavaScript, but that doesn't mean you're creating a website; you're still creating an application.

Comment: To clarify a bit further: phonegap bootstraps a native app with a webview and in this webview runs your mobile app based on javascript, html, css, but with the additional advantage of having access to the device assets via the cordova js-library.

Comment: yes, I know this but that time my client need that functionality that's why I asked here for confirmation about this is possible or not. Thanks to all